# iPhone animaion, how to flip a coin (2 UIImageview)?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Assume there are 2 `UIImageview` s, the front and back images of a coin. How to animate the 2 UIImageviews such that the face and the back is flipping (spinning) continuously? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off with `OpenGL` for this. But instead of two images from faces of a coin, if you're using Core Animation, you might think about animating one view from individual frames, where you have "snapshots" of a picture of a single coin in various stages of a coin flip.

Comment: I agree with Alex's answer about using snapshots. 2.5D animation is fine for flipping something flat like a card but on a coin it'll look a little cheap

Comment: Apple has some sample projects on their developer site. Definitely worth checking out.